# RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category READ is not supported in state standby

Tags: bash, oozie

If you want to know how I solved it, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43257926/copying-files-from-a-hdfs-directory-to-another-with-oozie-distcp-action/43307956#43307956).

I have a oozie workflow. There is a shell action inside.

```
  <action name="start_fair_usage">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
      <job-tracker>${JOB_TRACKER}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${NAME_NODE}</name-node>
      <exec>${start_fair_usage}</exec>      
      <argument>${today_without_dash}</argument>
      <argument>${yesterday_with_dash}</argument>
      <file>${start_fair_usage_path}#${start_fair_usage}</file>
      <capture-output/>
    </shell>
    <ok to="END"/>
    <error to="KILL"/>
  </action>
```

This action starts a script. start_fair_usage.sh

```
echo "today_without_dash="$today_without_dash
echo "yeasterday_with_dash="$yeasterday_with_dash

echo "-----------RUN copy mta-------------"
bash copy_file.sh mta $today_without_dash
echo "-----------RUN copy rcr-------------"
bash copy_file.sh rcr $today_without_dash
echo "-----------RUN copy sub-------------"
bash copy_file.sh sub $today_without_dash
```

Which in turn starts another script. copy_file.sh

```
# directories in which where sub mtr rcr files are kept
echo "directories"
dirs=(
    /user/comverse/data/${2}_B
    )

# clear the hdfs directory of old files and copy new files
echo "remove old files "${1}

hadoop fs -rm -skipTrash /apps/hive/warehouse/amd.db/fair_usage/fct_evkuzmin/file_${1}/*

for i in $(hadoop fs -ls "${dirs[@]}" | egrep ${1}.gz | awk -F " " '{print $8}')
do
    hadoop fs -cp $i /apps/hive/warehouse/amd.db/fair_usage/fct_evkuzmin/file_${1}
    echo "copy file - "${i}
done

echo "end copy "${1}" files"
```

How do I start the workflow so that it can copy files?

Comment: The exception is from the Hadoop Environment. Oozie is trying to connect with the StandBy Namenode inplace of Active Namenode. Check whether the Namenode host information is correct.

Comment: @frank I'm couldn't find what's the differnece between the StandBy and  Active nodes. But when I try to run a simple script `echo 'hi'` (for example) on the same node, it works.

Comment: Read about HDFS High Availability

Comment: _"StandBy and Active nodes"_  >> when HDFS is set up with High Availability, there are 2 NameNodes running active/passive *[there are also 3 JournalNodes and 3 ZooKepper nodes, quorums, etc.]* -- but you cannot know in advance which one is active at a given time. So applications have a list of 2 NN in `hdfs-site.xml` and they always contact #1 first -- if it is the active one, fine, otherwise you get that message about "STANDBY mode" and the app contacts #2, which is active, so it's fine. TL;DR **this is just a noisy warning, happens 50% of the time statistically, ignore it.**

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem ,below is the stack trace:

```
2017-07-03 18:07:24,208 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: reportBadBlock encountered RemoteException for block:  BP-455427998-10.120.117.100-1466433731629:blk_1140369410_67364810
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category WRITE is not supported in state standby
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.StandbyState.checkOperation(StandbyState.java:87)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode$NameNodeHAContext.checkOperation(NameNode.java:1774)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkOperation(FSNamesystem.java:1313)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.reportBadBlocks(FSNamesystem.java:6263)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.reportBadBlocks(NameNodeRpcServer.java:798)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.reportBadBlocks(DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:272)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.DatanodeProtocolProtos$DatanodeProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(DatanodeProtocolProtos.java:28766)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2045)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.reportBadBlocks(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.DatanodeProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.reportBadBlocks(DatanodeProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.java:290)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.ReportBadBlockAction.reportTo(ReportBadBlockAction.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.processQueueMessages(BPServiceActor.java:988)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.offerService(BPServiceActor.java:727)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:824)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If you are familiar with hadoop RPC, you will know that the above error log happends when RPC client(`DataNode`) trying to make a remote `RPC` call to the `RPC` Server(`NameNode`),`NodeNode` throw a exception because it is a standby one.So ,some of the above stacktrace was the server-side stack and some are the client-side stacktrace.

But the key is , does it has any bad influence to you `HDFS` system?
The answer is absolute **no**.

From `BPOffsetService.java`:

```
  void notifyNamenodeReceivingBlock(ExtendedBlock block, String storageUuid) {
checkBlock(block);
ReceivedDeletedBlockInfo bInfo = new ReceivedDeletedBlockInfo(
   block.getLocalBlock(), BlockStatus.RECEIVING_BLOCK, null);

for (BPServiceActor actor : bpServices) {
  actor.notifyNamenodeBlock(bInfo, storageUuid, false);
}
```

}

The `bpServices` store the rpc list of both namenodes , including the active and the standby one.Obviously , a same request it send to both namenodes ,at least one request will report a 'category WRITE is not supported in state standby***'error and the other one will succeed.
So ,no worries about it.
In your hdfs HA configurtion ,if you configure like this:

```
       <property>
            <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.datahdfsmaster</name>
            <value>namenode1,namenode2</value>
    </property>
```

And unfortunately ,if the namenode1 is the standby one , then you will receive much INFO-level log because namenode1 will be requested for some Operation and surely the NameNode-side checkOperation() will throw a INFO-level exception.